# I have a question regarding Control-m's migration from server to server

Tags: control-m

Just wondering if anyone knows how a migration of global variables would be transferred from server to server. Also, I'm new here. Nice to meet everyone and I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you do the fully automated migration then I think the global variables are handled for you. However I, being a control freak, have never gone with the fully automated migration and move stuff in stages, often with XML-based utilities.

The advantage here is that you have the opportunity to clean up your system as you migrate. If you use LIBMEMSYM (as opposed to global variables) then those files are easily copied across. However for global variables I simply list them out on the original server, drop them into a spreadsheet and define them on the new location via the ctmvar utility.

This might sound like amateur hour but bear in mind that you shouldn't go crazy with global variables. BMC recommend that you stick to a general maximum of 100 per Control-M Server; lots of global variables can lead to performance issues.

Good luck!

Comment: @ Mark thank you for your feedback! I'm in training for Control-m and I'm trying to assist in the process so I'll definitely see if this is an option!